# Question about changing the argument in range function through iterations

Tags: python, range

I'm a newbie so I'm really sorry if this is too basic of a question, but I just couldn't solve it on my own. Perhaps it's not considered complex enough ( at all ) which would explain why I couldn't find an adequate answer online.

I've made a tic-tac-toe program following the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python textbook, but modified it a tiny bit so it doesn't allow players to enter 'X'/'O' in already filled slots. Here's what it looks like :

```
theBoard = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
        'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
        'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}
def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L']+'|'+board['top-M']+'|'+board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L']+'|'+board['mid-M']+'|'+board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L']+'|'+board['low-M']+'|'+board['low-R'])

turn='X'
_range=9
for i in range(_range):
   printBoard(theBoard)
   print('''It is the '''+turn+''' player's turn.''')
   move=input()
   if theBoard[move]==' ':
      theBoard[move]=turn
   else:
      print('The slot is already filled !')
      _range+=1
   if turn=='X':
      turn ='O'
   else:
      turn='X'
printBoard(theBoard)
```

However, it doesn't seem like the _range variable is being increased by one at all through iterations where I intentionally enter 'X'\'O' in the slots where such symbols are already existent.

Is there something that I'm missing her ? Is there any way I could make this work as I planned it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: `range(_range)` creates a range object once at the beginning of the loop. Maybe you could just continue at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be easier to sanitize the input immediately via a `while` loop instead of increasing the range.

```
move = input(f"It is the {turn} player's turn.")
while theBoard[move]!=' ':
    move=input('The slot is already filled')
```

Your attempt did not work because you changed `_range` after it being used and it is not used after you changed it.